# how to validate 2 text boxes having the same validation requirement?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm finding it very difficult to validate 2 text boxes for matching it with a pattern for acadamic year like 2012-13. I've given differnt ids for both the text boxes n have tried to validate seperately but its not happening. Can any of you please help out. I'm a fresher.
i've attached my js code. I want an error message if the pattern is not found for both the text boxes.

```
   <html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

window.onchange=function check_it() {
    var ay = document.getElementById("ayear").value;
    var fy=document.getElementById("fyear").value;

    var pattern = /\d{4}-\d{2,4}$/;

    if(pattern.test(ay) && pattern.test(fy)){
        return true;
    } else {

       window.alert ("invalid");
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
<form   >

<p> This Report is prepared for the Current Acadamic Year(<input type="text" size="10"  id="ayear" >) and the Current Financial Year (<input type="text" size="10"  id="fyear" >) on behalf of the Institution.</p>


</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in your JavaScript console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this solution will work for you `onBlur` will be triggered automatically when you move your cursor from the text field. If you want you can add a `onClick` function too. Here is your code. Use it in the appropriate place.

```
<script>
function validate(){
var y = document.getElementById("errorResponse");
var x=document.forms["myForm"]["fval"].value;
var z=document.forms["myForm"]["sval"].value;

//Compare the expression

    if (x!=z){
        y.innerHTML = "Values not missing";
    }else{
        y.innerHTML = "Correct";
    }
 }
</script>


<form name="myForm">
First value: <input type="text" name="fval"/><br>
Second value: <input type="text" name="sval" onBlur = "validate()"/>
<div id = "errorResponse"></div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
window.onchange=function check_it() {
    var ay = document.getElementById("ayear").value;
    var fy=document.getElementById("fyear").value;

    var pattern = /^\d{4}-\d{2,4}$/;
    if(pattern.test(ay) && pattern.test(fy)){
        return true;
    } else {
        window.alert ("invalid");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Also, I'd suggest replacing your regex with this:

```
/^\d{4}-\d{2,4}$/
```

Because the other regex will also validate for `122012-2012345`

Now, the function above will only return `true` if both fields pass the test. Otherwise, it will return `false`.

---

Also, I'd suggest always using brackets (`{}`) with your `if/else`'s. You had a small issue in your code with those.

This:

```
if (pattern.test(ay))
    return false;
else
    window.alert ("invalid");
return true;
```

Should have been:

```
if (pattern.test(ay)){
    return false;
} else {
    window.alert ("invalid");
    return true;
}
```

**[Working Sample](http://fiddle.jshell.net/r8ppw/)**

Comment: yes sir, the first text box is not getting validated second text box is fine. which was vice-cersa before

Comment: @suhas: That's weird. Did you copy the code in the first example in my answer? That code should work.

Comment: Works for me..maybe we aren't understanding your question completely.  Does the jsfiddle example not work for you? http://fiddle.jshell.net/r8ppw/

Comment: I've now uploded the complete code. Can any one find what the mistake is?

Comment: The problem i'm finding is that the validation is not happening properly

Comment: in jsfiddle its working completely fine.butr not in mozilla firefox